# How are "cyclic" first-order linear differential equations called?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm interested in first-order linear differential equations which form a cycle with the variables. An example would be
$$\dot{x} = y \hspace{1cm} \dot{y} = z \hspace{1cm} \dot{z} = x$$
Does these types of differential equations have a name ? Because I'm interested in finding literature and in understanding if these kinds of ODE always diverge, or if there are solutions which converge and are stable, except for the trivial initial condition $x_0 = 0, y_0 = 0, z_0 = 0$. My intuition is that they always diverge, since even if the initial condition is set near zero, it will sooner or later build up to bigger and bigger derivatives.

Comment: Only about half, the smaller half, of the basis solutions diverge. Still, the set of stable solutions in the full solution space is thin, so numerical solutions will always eventually have a diverging term. // You might look into circulant, Toeplitz and Hankel matrices, one of them or something closely related corresponds to the structure of the system matrix here.

Comment: Thank you for the nice pointer

Answer (score 2):

If those equations hold then we must have $\dddot{x}=x$, by finding the roots of it’s characteristic equation you can find all solutions.